# Echo Suppression library?

Tags: c++, c, echo, voip, pjsip

I'm looking for an echo suppression library to put into a VoIP application (using pjsip). Open Source or commercial. The application is written in C++ (Windows, Mac and soon to come Linux).

I have tried several echo cancelers (both free and commercial), without good results. So I'm looking for something simpler that will give at least the user expecience users have been familiar with using Skype. The Echo Suppressor in pjsip does not work well enough for my use (it fails to provide good echo suppression on too many machines - both PC and Mac).

NB: Re-added the question, after someone mis-interpereted it as a duplicate about echo cancellation. Echo cancellation is a more modern and popular approach for handling echo in VoIP applications, but it is fundamentally different from Echo Suppression. Echo Suppression uses less CPU (= better battery life on laptops), and is more robust (modern PC hardware can make alot of obstacles that prevents echo cancellation from working). I am specifically /not/ looking for an Echo Canceling library.

Comment: In DOS you used to be able to say "ECHO OFF". I don't know what came of that, though.

Comment: The echo I want suppressed is in audio, not visually on a console :) [Echo suppressor in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_suppressor) But I'm looking for a software library, not an embedded circuit.

Comment: Eventually I gave up the search for an Echo Cancellation library, and ended up using the VoiceEngine library that is part of Googles WebRTC project. It includes a very good Echo Canceller (the best I've tried so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of research, we gave up both common open source and commercial AEC implementations. Then we moved our media stack to Google's Voice Engine (part of Chromes WebRTC code base), and guess what - AEC works very well most of the time (we still have some problems with Apple/OS X when using external speakers).

Comment: have you tried Adaptive Digital's echo cancellers? we measure google's AEC and it uses a lot of CPUs.

Comment: what about Andre Adrian AEC? [link](http://www.andreadrian.de/intercom/index.html)

Comment: @jgaa hi, can u please contact to me alex@cfc.io i'm interesting to buy u implementation code for pjsip.

Answer (score 1):

[speex](http://www.speex.org/) has echo cancellation in the reference library since it's part of the codec, and it seems to export that as part of the API so I think you might be able to use that. See [here](http://www.speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual/node7.html#SECTION00740000000000000000)

**EDIT** hmm, looks like that's what the one used by pjsip is... sorry, useless answer :(